# Is jQuery / Javascript code executed line by line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this code

```
    var customer_number = $("#customer_number").val();
    var data = <?php if(isset($questions)) {echo $questions; } else {echo '"";';} ?> 
    var records = [];

    $.each(data, function(key,value) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "api/suppression/checkifsuppressed", 
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'customer_number':customer_number, 'columnheader' : value.columnheader},
            success: function(result){
            if(parseInt(result) >= 1)
            {
                data.splice(key , 1);
            }
        }});
    });

    $.each(data, function(key,value) {
        records.push({
            agebracket: value.agebracket,
            agerestriction: value.agerestriction,
            child_count: value.child_count,
            child_enable_response: value.child_enable_response,
            child_sort_num: value.child_sort_num,
            columnheader: value.columnheader,
            costperlead: value.costperlead,
            created_at: value.created_at,
            deliveryassignment: value.deliveryassignment,
            id: value.id,
            is_child: value.is_child,
            isenabled: value.isenabled,
            ownhomeoptions: value.ownhomeoptions,
            ownhomerestriction: value.ownhomerestriction,
            parent_colheader: value.parent_colheader,
            po_num: value.po_num,
            postcodeexclusion: value.postcodeexclusion,
            postcodeinclusion: value.postcodeinclusion,
            postcoderestriction: value.postcoderestriction,
            question: value.question,
            sortorder: value.sortorder,
            telephoneoptions: value.telephoneoptions,
            telephonerestriction: value.telephonerestriction,
            updated_at: value.updated_at,
            parent_enable_response: value.parent_enable_response,
            child_lead_respponse: value.child_lead_respponse,
        });
    });

    console.log("The new data is..");
    console.log(data);

    console.log("The new records is..");
    console.log(records);
```

What I am doing is I have the variable `data` which has content in it let's say two records. And as you can see I have two `$.each` loop my question is that, are those two loop being executed at the same time? What I have in my first `$.each` is I loop in all the records of the `data` then for each record I am making an ajax call to check something in the database, if the database returns 1 or greater than 1 I will remove that current data in the `data` array. So I made a test.

The `data` has two records and will satisfy the condition in the first `$.each` which will remove one data in the array.

Then in my second `$.each` I'm just getting the `data` variable loop in it and whatever the content of it I am just copying it to my `records` array. But when I run the code I got this

[image]

As you can see, the `data` has now 1 record which I expected because it satisfies one condition in the fist loop. However in the result of my `records` array, why it has still 2 records in it? Did it get the original value of the `data` which has two records in it? It should be 1 because on the first loop I already modified the `data` array? This code will run on page load.

I'm new to jQuery.

Comment: Given your example... the first `$.each` will complete before the second begins. However, you may seeing some issues due to the fact that your AJAX call is asynchronous.

Comment: Yes, the second loop is probably executing before the ajax result comes back from the server.  You could probably just change the ajax calls to be synchronous.

Comment: yeah you could make the ajax synchronous, or you could do it correctly and use the callback function..

Comment: I tried using async: false but gave me error, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'columnheader' of undefined. I think it has issue on the second iteration?